# Codeception - What is the difference between cest and cept?

Tags: php, testing, tdd, codeception

I just started using TDD approach and came across codeception.

I searched the web a lot but didn't find a proper explanation or differentiation between `cest` and `cept` files in codeception.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Their format is the only difference.

Cept is a scenario-based format and Cest is a class based format.

#### Cept example:

```
<?php    
$I = new AcceptanceTester($scenario);
$I->wantTo('log in as regular user');
$I->amOnPage('/login');
$I->fillField('Username','john');
$I->fillField('Password','secret');
$I->click('Login');
$I->see('Hello john');
```

#### Cest example:

```
<?php
class UserCest
{
    public function loginAsRegularUser(\AcceptanceTester $I) 
    {
        $I->wantTo('log in as regular user');
        $I->amOnPage('/login');
        $I->fillField('Username','john');
        $I->fillField('Password','secret');
        $I->click('Login');
        $I->see('Hello john');            
    }
}
```

Non-developers may find the *Cept* format more friendly and approachable.  PHP developers may prefer the *Cest* format which is able to support multiple tests per file and easy reuse of code by adding additional private functions.

In the end it is just a matter of taste and you can choose the format you prefer.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a Cest with 2 test methods like

```
<?php
class UserCest
{
    public function test1(\AcceptanceTester $I) 
    {
        $I->see('Hello john');            
    }

    public function test2(\AcceptanceTester $I) 
    {
        $I->see('Hello jeff');            
    }
}
```

That is thew Equivalent to
test1Cept.php:

```
<?php
$I = new AcceptanceTester($scenario);
$I->see('Hello john');
```

test2Cept.php:

```
<?php
$I = new AcceptanceTester($scenario);
$I->see('Hello jeff');
```

It's just 2 different ways of structuring you test code

Comment: for me it didnt work, always only first test was run, but when i renamed file from Cept to Cest i realized later it is inevitable necessity it started to work for all methods not just first one what is confusing

Answer (score -1):

Not that I'm a Codeception expert but this description may help - http://codeception.com/docs/07-AdvancedUsage.

Comment: Link only answers are considered low quality on Stackoverflow